# Cannot import name warp_polar from skimage.transform

Tags: python

I want to use polar and log-polar transformation in Python. But, when I try to import warp_polar I get this error: 
cannot import name 'warp_polar' from 'skimage.transform'

Comment: I don't know, even I'm getting the same error, this maybe a bug in that skimage package, try reporting in their official Github page

Comment: share your actual code

Comment: I want to try this example.
https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_register_rotation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-transform-plot-register-rotation-py

Answer (score 0):

warp_polar is only available since skimage version 0.16, which is still in development.

You have two options now:

1. install the development version of scikit-image from source: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image#installation-from-source
2. copy the warp_polar function from https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/transform/_warps.py#L965 into your project